# Como alterar o background de um JDateChooser?

Tags: java, swing, jcalendar

Eu tenho um `JDateChooser` e gostaria de alterar o background quando ele ganhasse `focu`, porém eu não estou conseguindo.

Eu tentei fazer de algumas maneiras:

```
dataChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent().setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
```

ou

```
dataChooser.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
```

e isso eu coloquei dentro do evento de `focusGained`

```
import com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class BackGr extends JFrame {

    JDateChooser data = new JDateChooser();
    JPanel painel = new JPanel();

    public BackGr() {
        setSize(300, 150);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        painel.add(data);

        data.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                data.getDateEditor().getUiComponent().setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
                //data.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            }
        });

        add(painel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BackGr bg = new BackGr();
        bg.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, adicione um **[mcve]** do seu código para que seja possivel testar e ver o problema em execução.

Comment: @Articuno coloquei lá, desculpa !

Comment: O que significa esse `focu` que você destacou?

Comment: focu , no sentido de entrar com o cursor no campo, acho que escrevi errado.

Comment: A aplicação já abre com esse campo em foco?

Comment: nesse caso esta, porém eu testei sem iniciar direto com o focu, e o resultado é o mesmo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o objetivo é alterar diretamente o campo de texto, você precisa adicionar o evento no editor do `JDateChooser`. Para isso, recupere o componente editor através do método `getDateEditor()`:

```
JTextFieldDateEditor dateChooserEditor = ((JTextFieldDateEditor)data.getDateEditor());
```

Depois, adicione o evento de "foco" direto nele:

```
dateChooserEditor.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {

        dateChooserEditor.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {

    }
});
```

Porém, dessa forma vai alterar permanentemente o background do componente. Se o objetivo é somente mudar quando estiver focado nele, uma alternativa é armazenar a cor padrão do background e restaure-a quando perder o foco:

```
dateChooserEditor.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

    Color defaultBG = dateChooserEditor.getBackground();

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {

        dateChooserEditor.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {

        dateChooserEditor.setBackground(defaultBG);
    }
});
```

Veja um exemplo da alteração acima em pratica:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>